# Comparing strings with etoolbox

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox, strings

I'm having an hard time understanding how to use the various options `etoolbox` has for comparing strings. Let's consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{ContNationality}
\setcounter{ContNationality}{2}

\newcommand{\Nationality}{%
    \ifcase\value{ContNationality}\or%
        {ita}\or{eng}\or{fra}%
    \fi%
}%

\begin{document}

\expandafter\ifdefstring{\Nationality}{ita}{You are italian}{}%
\expandafter\ifdefstring{\Nationality}{eng}{You are english}{}%
\expandafter\ifdefstring{\Nationality}{fra}{You are french}{}%

\end{document}
```

I put that `\expandafter` because `\ifdefstrings` won't expand the content of the command, according to the package guide. Yet, if I execute such code, with or without the `\expandafter`, the resulting pdf will only include a paragraph with a "b". Quite of an astonishing outcome, I have to say.

So, how can I manage this situation and have the conditionals there to work as I want?

**EDIT:**

As you pointed out, I wrote `\ifvalue` instead of `\ifcase\value`. My mistake.

**EDIT 2:**

I didn't state this because I thought it wasn't important: the value of `\Nationality` needs to be dynamic, because actually in the main document I'm working on it is called 100 times, always with a different value of the `ContNationality` counter.

The fact that there is such counter is more or less fixed by the fact that the value of `\Nationality` needs to be random, and that I'm using the `lcg` package which assigns random values to counters. So, basically, I give a random value to that counter and then I use it to determine the random value of `\Nationality`.

A larger MWE would be the following. I implemented Steven B. Segletes's solution - which works perfectly, I see - which looked like the most user-friendly option to me. I saw egreg's one, and I'm sure it works, but if I copy-paste it in my document I receive a very long list of errors, probably given by the fact that I don't have the very-last version of LaTeX, and I don't understand how to download it. Moreover, I would like to avoid LaTeX3-based solutions because I really don't know anything of that language and I'd prefer to use answers that I understand how they work, so that of course I can work with them in case I need to change my code's behaviour.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[last=2147483647]{lcg}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcounter{ContNationality}
\setcounter{ContNationality}{2}
\newcounter{Cycles}
\newcounter{SEED}

\newcommand{\Random}[3]{%
    \providecommand{\NewSeed}{%
        \reinitrand[last=2147483647, seed=\value{SEED}]%
        \rand%
        \setcounter{SEED}{\therand}%
        \typeout{Il seed attualmente è \theSEED}%
    }%
    \reinitrand[first=#1,last=#2,seed=\value{SEED}]%
    \rand%
    \setcounter{#3}{\value{rand}}%
    \NewSeed%
}

\newcommand{\Nationality}{%
    \edef\theNationality{%
        \ifcase\value{ContNationality}%
            \or ita%
            \or eng%
            \or fra%
        \fi%
    }%
}

\begin{document}%
    %
    \rand%
    \setcounter{SEED}{\value{rand}}%
    \setcounter{Cycles}{0}%
    \whiledo{\value{Cycles}<10}{%
        \addtocounter{Cycles}{1}%
        \Random{1}{3}{ContNationality}%
        \Nationality%
        \ifdefstring{\theNationality}{ita}{You are Italian}{}%
        \ifdefstring{\theNationality}{eng}{You are English}{}%
        \ifdefstring{\theNationality}{fra}{You are French}{}%
    \\
    }%  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David already explained why the `\epandafter` is useless. But the second one which would expand `\Nationality` wouldn't help either, since the definition of `\Natioanlity` never is the same as the strings you are testing it with. At some point you must expand it completely *before* the comparison. The easiest way is to `\edef` `\Nationality` (unless you don't want it to be fixed but be able to change it mid-document). BTW: there is no `\ifvalue` that I know of. I guess you want `\ifcase\value{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{ContNationality}
\setcounter{ContNationality}{2}

\newcommand{\Nationality}{}
\edef\Nationality{%
  \ifcase\value{ContNationality}
  \or ita%
  \or eng%
  \or fra%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\ifdefstring{\Nationality}{ita}{You are Italian}{}%
\ifdefstring{\Nationality}{eng}{You are English}{}%
\ifdefstring{\Nationality}{fra}{You are French}{}%

\end{document}
```

PS: just seeing that egreg already explained the issues. I'll leave the answer anyway as it doesn't use expl3.

Comment: Of course, the way you have it set up, you can only use it once.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that's what I mean by “*unless you don't want it to be fixed but be able to change it mid-document*” – it's not clear from the question how the use-case will be…

Comment: If you define it `\newcommand{\Nationality}{%
\edef\theNationality{%
  \ifcase\value{ContNationality}%
  \or ita%
  \or eng%
  \or fra%
  \fi%
}}`, then you can perform the test repeatedly with `\Nationality
\ifdefstring{\theNationality}{ita}{You are Italian}{}%
\ifdefstring{\theNationality}{eng}{You are English}{}%
\ifdefstring{\theNationality}{fra}{You are French}{}%`, that is, by reinvoking `\Nationality` prior to the next test.

Comment: `\Nationality` would in fact be called several times across the document. This of course is just a MWE; in the main document there is a cycle that is repeated 100 times, and every time it calls `\Nationality` with a possibly different value of `ContNationality`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks. I guess your comment is for the OP? I can think of several ways to achieve a dynamic `\Nationality`… Personally I'd probably not use a counter but prefer something like `\setnationality{eng}` which does the appropriate definition…

Comment: I'll specify in the opening post that it's dynamic

Comment: @ilmietitore egreg's solution *is* dynamic :)

Comment: I updated the post. As I wrote above, egreg's solution is unfriendly to me because it uses LaTeX3, which I don't know anything of. I'll go with the smooth solution proposed by @StevenB.Segletes here. For now I'll indicate this as a correct answer, since the solution came out of its comments; Steven, if you'll post your solution in a new answer I'll indicate yours as correct.

Comment: @ilmietitore I think clemens deserves the credit.  Maybe he can incorporate a revision to show either my approach or a better one that achieves re-usability of the macro.

Comment: I'll add something but it will have to wait a few days. I am quite short of time the next days.

Answer (score 1):

```
\expandafter\ifdefstring{\Nationality
```

applies expansion to `{` which doesn't expand, you meant

```
\expandafter\ifdefstring\expandafter{\Nationality
```

However that will still only expand `\Nationality` one step

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what `\ifdefstring` does. Its first argument is a macro and its *first level* expansion is compared to the second argument. The first level expansion of `\Nationality` is not a string, but the whole `\ifcase\value...\fi`.

Here's an expandable test based on `expl3`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{ContNationality}
\setcounter{ContNationality}{2}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\Nationality}{}
 {
  \int_case:nn { \value{ContNationality} }
   {
    {1}{ita}
    {2}{eng}
    {3}{fra}
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifdefstringx}{mmmm}
 {
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{ita}{You are italian}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{eng}{You are english}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{fra}{You are french}{}\par

\setcounter{ContNationality}{1}

\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{ita}{You are italian}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{eng}{You are english}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{fra}{You are french}{}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a solution based on `etoolbox`, you can do as follows (but, differently from the above solution this is not expandable).

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{ContNationality}
\setcounter{ContNationality}{2}

\newcommand{\Nationality}{%
  \ifcase\value{ContNationality}\or
  ita\or
  eng\or
  fra\fi
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifdefstringx}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{#1}%
  \ifdefstring{\x}{#2}{\endgroup\@firstoftwo}{\endgroup\@secondoftwo}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{ita}{You are italian}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{eng}{You are english}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{fra}{You are french}{}\par

\setcounter{ContNationality}{1}

\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{ita}{You are italian}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{eng}{You are english}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{fra}{You are french}{}\par

\end{document}
```

If you want an expandable text:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{ContNationality}
\setcounter{ContNationality}{2}

\newcommand{\Nationality}{%
  \ifcase\value{ContNationality}\or
  \expandafter\itastring\or
  \expandafter\engstring\or
  \expandafter\frastring\fi
}
\newcommand{\itastring}{ita}
\newcommand{\engstring}{eng}
\newcommand{\frastring}{fra}

\newcommand{\ifdefstringx}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\romannumeral-`Q#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{ita}{You are italian}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{eng}{You are english}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{fra}{You are french}{}\par

\setcounter{ContNationality}{1}

\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{ita}{You are italian}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{eng}{You are english}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{fra}{You are french}{}\par

\end{document}
```

Alternatively

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\newcounter{ContNationality}
\setcounter{ContNationality}{2}

\newcommand{\Nationality}{%
  \ifcase\value{ContNationality}\or
  ita\or
  eng\or
  fra\fi
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifdefstringx}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{ita}{You are italian}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{eng}{You are english}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{fra}{You are french}{}\par

\setcounter{ContNationality}{1}

\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{ita}{You are italian}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{eng}{You are english}{}\par
\ifdefstringx{\Nationality}{fra}{You are french}{}\par

\end{document}
```