# XeLaTeX + \ifthenelse:

Tags: xetex, conditionals

I use XelaTeX to produce my CV.

Currently, I want to update it and have both Slovak and English CV within one document.

I want to have all strings of one language grouped in the preamble, same for the other. (That is, I don’t want to have the string after `\begin{document}`).

I want to create `\cvlang` using `\def \cvlang {sk}  % Options: en | sk`. This way I can switch between languages quite easily.

Now, I have no idea, how to check what is the current value of the `\cvlang`. I want to create something like this (`if` syntax borrowed from Javascript; incorporated some TeX commands):

```
if (\cvlang == "sk"){
  \def \lgdatebirthplace {Dátum a miesto\\ narodenia}
  \def \lgaddress {Adresa}
  \def \lgphone {Telefón}
  \def \lgemail {Email}
}else if{
  \def \lgdatebirthplace {Date and place of birth}
  \def \lgaddress {Address}
  \def \lgphone {Phone}
  \def \lgemail {Email}
}
```

I don’t care about the package/command/syntax—it can be anything.

I tried to use `ifthen` package, but I’ve some errors at PDF compilation:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{sk}}{
    \def \lgdatebirthplace {Dátum a miesto\\ narodenia}
    \def \lgaddress {Adresa}
    \def \lgphone {Telefón}
    \def \lgemail {Email}
}{
  \def \lgdatebirthplace {Date and place of birth}
  \def \lgaddress {Address}
  \def \lgphone {Phone}
  \def \lgemail {Email}
}%
```

I tried to use `pdftexcmds` package, however, this does not work either:

```
% \usepackage{pdftexcmds}
% \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\cvlang}{sk}{
  \def \lgdatebirthplace {Dátum a miesto\\ narodenia}
  \def \lgaddress {Adresa}
  \def \lgphone {Telefón}
  \def \lgemail {Email}
\else
  \def \lgdatebirthplace {Date and place of birth}
  \def \lgaddress {Address}
  \def \lgphone {Phone}
  \def \lgemail {Email}
\fi
```

Questions and answers I checked and tried to implement:
 - [On testing two fully expanded character strings for equality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59565/on-testing-two-fully-expanded-character-strings-for-equality)

- [Comparing strings with etoolbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371642/comparing-strings-with-etoolbox)

PS—I am quite new to TeX and I have never used any conditionals in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for ifthen here. Add your definitions to the babel interface:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\addto\extrasslovak{%
 \def \lgdatebirthplace {Dátum a miesto}}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
 \def \lgdatebirthplace {Date and place of birth}}

\begin{document}
\lgdatebirthplace

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works as expected, however, I use some of these ‘variables’ (i.e. command definitions that outputs a string) with `hyperref` packages, concreately with `hypersetup`, which now throughs errors (`Undefined control sequence. <argument> \pdfauthor`). It looks like this: `\hypersetup{ pdfauthor={\pdfauthor}, pdftitle={\pdftitle}, pdfsubject={\pdfsubtitle}, pdfkeywords={\pdfkeywords}, pdfsubject={\pdfsubject} }`.

Comment: Ask a new question. And add a sensible minimal example.

Comment: Okay, I did as you suggested → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478958/xelatex-babel-addto-extraslang-hyperref